# android notification shows just the last notificatoin

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

I have application android which gives data from server, i want to make notifications, one notification for each row of data, I want when the user press on the notification, an activity is triggered, i want to do all that using android service, i could do all of that.

my problem is that whatever the notification the user press, it just shows the last row of data.

code:

```
lient client = new Client(Configuration.getServer());
        String str = client.getBaseURI("offers");
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject oneOffer = json.getJSONObject(i);
                int offerID = oneOffer.getInt("ID");
                String offerDescriptoin = oneOffer.getString("Description");
                String endDate = oneOffer.getString("EndDate");
                String startDate = oneOffer.getString("StartDate");
                JSONObject restaurant = oneOffer.getJSONObject("Restaurant");
                int restaruantID = restaurant.getInt("ID");
                String restaurantName = restaurant.getString("Name");
                Offer offer = new Offer(offerID, startDate, endDate,
                        offerDescriptoin, new Restaurant(restaruantID,
                                restaurantName));
                Log.d("DES", offerDescriptoin);
                Offer.getAllOffers().put(offer.getID(), offer);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OfferNotification.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        intent, 0);
                Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "call", pIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "more", pIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "add more", pIntent)
                        .setContentTitle("Offer from " + restaurantName)
                        .setContentText(offerDescriptoin).setSound(soundUri);
                // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, OfferNotification.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("offerID", offer.getID());
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

                stackBuilder.addParentStack(OfferNotification.class);

                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(offer.getID(), mBuilder.build());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in the following call
 **mNotificationManager.notify(offer.getID(), mBuilder.build());**

the ID passed is unique otherwise any pending notifications with matching ID will be replaced.

Check the documentation too

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html